# Kubernetes nginx ingress setup to get visitor's real IP using Cloudflare

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ingress, cloudflare

I have a kubernetes setup as below using Cloudflare as my DNS hosting. The domain is on Cloudflare and it's proxied.

[image]

I tried to search about how to make my nginx ingress to get the visitor's real IP but I couldn't make it work as I deployed the ingress using Helm.
There are some questions that I want to clarify to understand this deeply.

1- Is the diagram I created correct? To my understanding, there is my cloud provider load balancer which works as transparent, right?

2- How can I modify the Helm to add visitor's IP in the nginx logs?